# Inserting Polygon data into PostGIS using Python

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, polygon, psycopg2

I am able to insert polygon data manually into a postGres DB with one column having polygon datatype however, when I try to do the same dynamically it is not working.

This works.

```
cur.execute("INSERT into  public.test(timestamp,poly) values (now(),'((2,2),(3,4),(3,6),(1,1))');")
```

This doesnt.

```
    coords='((2,2),(3,4),(3,6),(1,1))'
    cur = cnn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT into  public.test(timestamp,poly) values (now(),'coords');")
```

so only difference is that , this time I am converting the same co ordinates into a tuple of tuples and passing that as a variable into the query.

> Error: psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: parse error - invalid geometry

Comment: Probably because it needs to be an actual string *literal*; the string itself needs to be wrapped in `'`

Comment: @geozelot , I did it, there is a " ' " around the coords variable.

Comment: Those `'` above declares a string *in Python*, but PostgreSQL needs a string that is *wrapped* in `'`; try `coords = "'((2,2),(3,4),(3,6),(1,1))'" `

Comment: @geozelot Hard luck :-( doesnt work < i get the below error

Comment: psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type polygon: "coords"
LINE 1: ...T into  public.test(timestamp,poly) values (now(),'coords');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*psycopg2* either needs a string *literal* wrapped in `'` when **building** the string, or get passed a value properly via the parameter interface. So either do:

```
coords = "'((2,2),(3,4),(3,6),(1,1))'"  # note the "'"

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO public.test(timestamp, poly) VALUES(NOW(), " + coords + ");")

# this builds the string with concatenating the '-wrapped string literal to the statement
# note that NOW() is a valid PostgreSQL function
```

or, **the recommended way** to have *psycopg2* take care of properly substituting parameters (to e.g. safeguard against SQL injection):

```
coords = '((2,2),(3,4),(3,6),(1,1))'  # no wrapping needed here

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO public.test(timestamp, poly) VALUES(NOW(), %s);", [coords])

# parameters are correctly formatted using specific wildcards, e.g. %s for string literals
```

---

Running your example command

```
 cur.execute("INSERT into  public.test(timestamp,poly) values (now(),'coords');")
```

will result in the query

```
INSERT into public.test(timestamp,poly) values (now(),'coords');
```

where `'coords'` is passed in directly (not replaced with the *Python* variable), and due to the `'` gets treated as string by PostgreSQL.